# Passing a parameter in char is printed correctly with printf but not with write

Tags: c, parameters, printf

I have a variable

```
char buffer[250] = "Your score is %d";
```

I print it like

```
printf(buffer, 50);
```

which displays `Your score is 50`

When i use

```
write(connfg, buffer, 50);
```

to print it to a client it displays `%d` instead of `50`

How can i make it display the same message as the server with printf?

Comment: that's why I said to look into `sprintf` in your previous post.

Comment: If you want formatted IO to a file descriptor and you're on POSIX, then use [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html).  Otherwise, you can't do it directly; `write` is a low-level IO facility so you have to format your string with `sprintf()` and then write the formatted string with `write()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use snprintf:

```
char buffer[250] =  "Your score is %d" ;
char temp[sizeof( buffer)] ;
snprintf( temp , sizeof( temp ) , buffer , 50 ) ;

printf("%s" , buffer ) ;
```

and then write buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` properly prints because it is a wrapper function which do all format conversions before calling write on `stdout`

`write()` wont print value because simply writes whatever in the buffer in to file/device file,

For your information, third argument of the `write()` call is count of the bytes to be written in to the file/device file.

Comment: `write` does not do any character interpretation, ASCII or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
#define SCORE "Your score is %d"
```

Anyway, I can see that you allocate a lot of memory for a short message. If it not used afterwards you can use:

```
char buffer[] = "Your score is %d";
```